# Distributed files over two servers

Tags: proxy, storage

Lets say I got a fast (connection) but low-storage server (S1) and a slow but much-storage server (S2). Is it (practically) possible to use the server S1 as a "proxy" for files? I.e. there is a folder "huge files" on S1, where the files actually get written to S2 (no problem so far with a mount) and also conserve user permissions. So - for example - if "User 1" writes "File 1" into the "huge files" folder, "User 2" can read but not modify it.

Note: S1 is accessed via SFTP, as it seemed like the best solution for filetransfer via www.
Note 2: Both S1 and S2 run linux/ubuntu)

For security only S1 should be allowed to connect to S2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scenario might call (if not shout) for iSCSI, which is basically SCSI over Ethernet.
Personally i only have played around with it once, but it seemed worth it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI

Comment: Thanks for the hint! This looks perfect :)
Is it feasible to use iSCSI over WAN? From the looks of it, it supports pretty strong authentication, but are there any issues with (somewhat) higher pings / how much overhead does it produce?

Comment: iSCSI over WAN does not sound like the best idea. But as i mentioned i don't have much experience with it. I could imagine that your ping translates to access time. So it might impact your speed less if you only have large files to transfer and more if you run a database over it or suchlike.

Comment: it will be > 5 GB HD films in 99% of the cases, so access times ... jeah :D

Comment: yeah, then it might be an issue during playback when you skip around...i guess you can live with that. :-)